# Naviagate to a View when a RibbonTabItem is selected.[MVVM,PRISM]

Tags: mvvm, navigation, prism, ribbon

I have each `Module` has a `RibbonTabItem`. I want to navigate to the module's MainView when Ribbon Tab is selected. I tried to bind to The Ribbon's SelectedTabItem property to a property in the ShellViewModel but when I click on tabs the property is not reached. Seems like the databinding is not working.

- How can I fix that if it's a good way, or what can be a good way to reach this requirement ?

Comment: Please feel free to ask if any detail requested.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but you really shouldn't use the Tab items in the Ribbon control as view switching tabs. That's not what a ribbon does in any normal application, and will confuse users.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. In my case each Module is really independent, that's why we ended up to this structure.

Comment: The tabs on the ribbon are supposed to show other controls on the ribbon (as an alternative to drop-down menus), not to switch between pages in the application. For example, switching ribbon tabs in MS word does not switch between documents, it just reveals different buttons on the ribbon. You shouldn't go against standard UI patterns in your application. This means you should probably have another tab control inside the ribbon window, or, possibly, that a ribbon isn't suitable for your needs.